# System.Debug and System.Threading Reference Error

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, system.diagnostics

Error Message
'ThreadState' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Threading.ThreadState' and 'System.Diagnostics.ThreadState'

I am trying to debug C# Class .cs and am using Debug.Writeline for code debugging...

But am getting an error above!!

Is there another way to debug C# Code Classes ? I tried Console.Writeline() and Alert.Show and Message.Show and have not found another effective way to debug web application C# classes or way around the ambiguous reference !!

Comment: This is a compilation error right? In this case you just have to add the namespace in front of the ThreadState identifiers in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fully qualified names for the offending enum, or don't do a `using System.Diagnostics` at all (and fully qualify the `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` calls instead).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by doing as follows. Put this using statement near all your other using statements:

```
using TheThreadState = System.Threading.ThreadState;
```

Now use TheThreadState on you code.

Comment: While this is technically correct, I personally never use such aliases because it is very confusing when reading the code out of sight of the `using`...

Comment: I believe it is a matter of taste. Anyway, I added my answer for the sake of completeness.